# Overflow icon kitkat 4.4.2

Tags: android, icons, overflow, toolbar

I am trying to replace overflow three dots icon to a custom icon, it works perfectly fine on android 5.1 but on kitkat 4.4.2 version it's just ignore this and set default icon. I'm using android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:actionOverflowButtonStyle">@style/over</item>
</style>

<style name="over" parent="Widget.AppCompat.ActionButton.Overflow">
    <item name="android:src">@drawable/ic_action_dots</item>

</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try to use below code in v19/styles.xml

```
<style name="anotherName" parent="AppTheme">
   <item name="actionOverflowButtonStyle">@style/over</item>
</style>
```

the important things is to remove the android namespace